# How to properly sync Gmail with Apple products - OS X and iOS, via iCloud or Exchange?

Tags: data-synchronization, gmail, google-calendar, google-sync

I am a happy `@gmail.com` user and do not plan to switch to `@me.com` in the foreseeable future, still I do have a Mac and an iPhone and I do want to keep all my info in sync.

So far I used the Gmail Exchange setup (`m.google.com` method) because this allowed me to sync `calendar` and `email`.

What is the best way to use Gmail contacts and calendar with Apple OS X and iOS?

As I do have an active iCloud account, does it bring any new functionality for a gmail user?

How can I sync tasks and notes from Gmail with iOS?

Answer (score 2):

Using iCloud doesn't really add new features for a Gmail user.

#### Contacts

Contacts on iOS are perfectly synced when using Google via Exchange.
Contacts on Mac OS X are synced using Address Book "Sync with Google" feature.

#### Calendar

Calendar is a bit more tricky.
On iOS, you have to activate each calendar individually in http://m.google.com/sync. But then, it syncs perfectly.
On Mac OS X, it can also be added to iCal, except it's via "Delegates".

It works but doesn't feel as *just work* as iCould does.

#### Mail

Mail has it's quirks, too.
On iOS, via Exchange, it doesn't bring all the Gmail goodness (archiving, etc.). And it miss push via the Gmail template.
On Mac OS X, via Mail, it's the same, archiving puts the mail in an "Archive" folder instead of the "All Mails" one.
Using an app like Sparrow resolve this issue.

---

To conclude, iCloud, like using the iWork suite instead of say Office, doesn't add value, but it feels more integrated with the OS (whether it's Mac OS or iOS).

Comment: Personally, I've move my calendars and contacts to iCloud, but kept my mail on Gmail (but mostly because I don't want to ask my contacts to change my default email address). But I've tried Mail on iCloud and it sure feel well integrated, having push for mail back is nice (I really don't like Google via Exchange) and having only 2 accounts instead of three is quite nice (but that's only because I'm a neat freak).